# refactoring multi-dimensional if/else conditions

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, conditional-statements

I'm writing in Swift, but the question is really language agnostic.

I have two variables, each of which could have multiple - but discrete - values. The various combinations of the two values lead to different behavior.

I need to consider all combinations and execute the appropriate code. What's the cleanest/easiest-to-maintain way to do this?

Graphically, it would look like this:

```
var2 / var1 |    A    |    B    |    C    |
------------|---------|---------|---------|
Z           |(A && Z) |(B && Z) |(C && Z) |
------------|---------|---------|---------|
Y           |(A && Y) |(B && Y) |(C && Y) |
------------|---------|---------|---------|
X           |(A && X) |(B && X) |(C && X) |
-------------------------------------------
```

You could imagine, with a third variable, the matrix becomes 3-dimensional, etc. which is why I'm interested in a generalizable solution, not necessarily a specific solution for my particular project.

I could go multiple if/else:

```
if (var1 == A && var2 == Z) {}
else if (var1 == B && var2 == Z) {}
else if ...
```

But that sounds awful.

Currently, I'm using one if/else and the same switch over and over:

```
if var1 == A {
    switch var2 {
        case Z:
        case Y:
        case X:
    }
} else if var1 == B {
    switch var2 {
        case Z:
        case Y:
        case X:
    }
} ...
```

But reusing the same switch tells me I'm doing it wrong.

Is this a case for polymorphism? That concept is a bit nebulous to me, and I don't quite philosophically get it. Is there a better way?

My real-life example is a calculator-type app where behavior depends not only on the button pressed, but also the *previous* button pressed, i.e. pressing '=' after a '#' is different than pressing '=' after '+' is different than pressing '+' after '=' is different than pressing a '#' after a '#', etc... So I'm comparing the current button pressed to the previous button pressed to determine the behavior of the calculator.

Comment: Are the actions associated with the different cases really completely different from each other or are there repetitions or patterns?

Comment: Sure, the actions fall in to a couple of different general bins. My particular switch has something more like "case Z: ... case Y, X: ... case W, V, U: ... but I'm still interested in the philosophical discussion of how to handle this type of conditional behavior :)

Comment: You need a *parser*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have complicated conditionals, a good approach is to separate the definition of the rules as much as possible from the actual workflow (evaluation of conditions, calling the action functions).

I would define a mapping as follows:

```
(var1, var2, ...) -> ActionFunction
```

This could be implemented as a function that takes all of your variables as inputs and returns a reference to another function that should be called in this case.

The actual mapping rules could be defined as an n-dimensional array where n is your number of input variables. The array could be stored as a constant within the program but it might also make sense to use an external file or a database for this.